# set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, apache, wamp, execution-time

I need to set `set_time_limit(0);` in my PHP script but I get

> **Warning:** set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons

I already tried increasing `max_execution_time` property in my php.ini with no effect. I'm running WAMP 2.4 with Apache 2.4.4 and PHP 5.4.12.

EDIT: I'm running it on my localhost, not shared hosting

Comment: On shared hosting? Contact your web host.

Comment: On shared hosting? They won't let you.

Comment: Why do you need unbound execution time?

Comment: @MikeBrant: I think that's out of the bounds but there could be a  million reasons why to do that.

Comment: On my localhost. I need it cause I'm downloading large amount of data from different server in xml and process it and than save into my database. Hundereds of MB of data and it can take several hours.

Comment: @budwiser The reason I ask is because many times, you see more novice programmers resorting to just blindly increasing timeouts rather than looking at their code to figure out why it takes so long to run, and how they could get it to run more efficiently.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Aah, I see. I think in many cases the reason is that shared hosts won't let you run a script in CLI, where by default you wouldn't have an execution time limit, so you have to run it in a browser and the next step is to look for a way to reduce the script execution time :)

Comment: Wamp Server 2.4 does not ship with the php.ini setting `disable_functions` set to anything so its nto that unless you added it. Have you changed anything in php.ini ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK looks like I was just stupid... I had .htaccess file in the root folder and due to that I was running the script not from my localhost but from shared hosting where obviously it failed... after removing the .htaccess it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `set_time_limit` is disabled in your `php.ini`'s [disable functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions). Try if removing `set_time_limit` from there helps you.

Comment: I think this is not the case.
It's just `disable_functions =` in my php.ini (empty string)

Comment: Well, the thing is that `set_time_limit()` **is disabled** in your system. You didn't specify what configuration you're using so it's impossible to tell, why you're not allowed to alter it. But what is almost certain, somewhere in your config, it is set disabled.

Comment: @budwiser, Hmm, can this disabling be overridden by perdirectory htaccess?

Comment: @Pacerier No. That would kind of remove the whole point of the feature :)

Answer (score 1):

Web hosting companies do this to prevent you from running very-long-running processes that could impact the availability of other websites sharing the server.

If you need to run on shared hosting, you'll need to find a way of doing what you need in smaller chunks.